# JavaFX setCellValueFactory cannot retrieve property IllegalAcessException

Tags: java, debugging, javafx, fxml, illegalaccessexception

I've checked at least 20 other threads on the subject and tried to debug this the best I can, but I have no clue why it won't work. I want my "addButton" to add my data into my TableView from the TextBoxes when the button is pressed.

My data class:

```
package org.application;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Credits {
    private SimpleStringProperty title;
    private SimpleStringProperty occupation;
    private SimpleStringProperty person;

    public Credits (String title, String occupation, String person){
        this.title = new SimpleStringProperty(title);
        this.occupation = new SimpleStringProperty(occupation);
        this.person = new SimpleStringProperty(person);
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title.get();
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title.set(title);
    }

    public String getOccupation() {
        return this.occupation.get();
    }

    public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
        this.occupation.set(occupation);
    }

    public String getPerson() {
        return this.person.get();
    }

    public void setPerson(String name) {
        this.person.set(name);
    }

}
```

Snippit of the important part of my Controller class

```
    public Button searchButton;
    public Button addButton;
    public Button deleteButton;
    public Button updateButton;
    public TextField searchBox;
    public TextField setTitleBox;
    public TextField setOccupationBox;
    public TextField setPersonBox;
    public TableView creditTable;
    public TableColumn title;
    public TableColumn occupation;
    public TableColumn person;
    public ListView test;

    final ObservableList<Credits> credits = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public void initialize() {
        title.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Credits, String>("title"));
        occupation.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Credits, String>("occupation"));
        person.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Credits, String>("person"));
    }

    public void addButton(ActionEvent event) {
        String title = setTitleBox.getText();
        String occupation = setOccupationBox.getText();
        String person = setPersonBox.getText();
        credits.add(new Credits(title, occupation, person));
        creditTable.setItems(credits);
    }
```

fxml file:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" styleClass="rightSide" stylesheets="@../../ECMS.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.presentation.MainMenu">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="loginButton" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToLoginScreen" styleClass="loginButton" text="Login" />
      <TextField fx:id="searchBox" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="108.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="195.0" promptText="Name" />
      <Button fx:id="searchButton" layoutX="214.0" layoutY="108.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" styleClass="loginButton" text="Search" />
      <Button fx:id="helpButton" layoutX="63.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToHelpPopup" styleClass="loginButton" text="Help" />
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="86.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="162.0" text="Search for productions:">

         <font>
            <Font name="Ebrima Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font></Label>
      <ListView fx:id="test" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="143.0" prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="300.0" />
      <Button fx:id="closeButton" layoutX="775.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#closeButtonAction" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="25.0" styleClass="closeButton" text="X">
         <font>
            <Font name="Eras Bold ITC" size="12.0" />
         </font></Button>
      <Button fx:id="addButton" layoutX="363.0" layoutY="93.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addButton" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Add" />
      <Button fx:id="deleteButton" layoutX="504.0" layoutY="93.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Delete" />
      <Button fx:id="updateButton" layoutX="652.0" layoutY="93.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Update" />
      <TableView fx:id="creditTable" editable="true" layoutX="332.0" layoutY="143.0" prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="450.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="title" prefWidth="147.0" text="Title" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="occupation" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="132.0" text="Occupation" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="person" minWidth="-1.0" prefWidth="170.0" text="Person" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <TextField fx:id="setPersonBox" layoutX="634.0" layoutY="54.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="136.0" promptText="Person" />
      <Label layoutX="500.0" layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="114.0" text="Add production:">
         <font>
            <Font name="Ebrima Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="setOccupationBox" layoutX="489.0" layoutY="54.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="136.0" promptText="Occupation" />
      <TextField fx:id="setTitleBox" layoutX="345.0" layoutY="54.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="136.0" promptText="Title" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The error: (It does this error for every one of the 3 CellProperty lines, this is just 1 but they are all pretty much identical).

```
Apr 19, 2020 7:20:12 PM javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory getCellDataReflectively
WARNING: Can not retrieve property 'title' in PropertyValueFactory: javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory@210cabaf with provided class type: class org.application.Credits
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module javafx.base cannot access class org.application.Credits (in module org.example) because module org.example does not open org.application to javafx.base
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.property.PropertyReference.get(PropertyReference.java:176)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.getCellDataReflectively(PropertyValueFactory.java:184)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.call(PropertyValueFactory.java:154)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.call(PropertyValueFactory.java:133)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:593)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:578)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:646)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:469)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:120)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.updateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:539)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.<init>(TableRowSkinBase.java:159)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:213)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:897)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9540)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.applyCss(Node.java:9627)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1749)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1726)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1852)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2755)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1245)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1206)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:576)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2482)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:412)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:438)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:563)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:543)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:536)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:342)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module javafx.base cannot access class org.application.Credits (in module org.example) because module org.example does not open org.application to javafx.base
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.property.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:69)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.property.PropertyReference.get(PropertyReference.java:174)
    ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception arises because `PropertyValueFactory` uses reflection to access method calls in your model class `Credits`. Because your module is not opened for such access to the `javafx.base` module, you get the `IllegalAccessException` you posted.

You can fix this by adding a line like the following to your `module-info.java` file:

```
opens org.application to javafx.base ;
```

Perhaps a better approach is to avoid using `PropertyValueFactory`. That class was really designed because, prior to Java 8 and lambda expressions, creating a `CellValueFactory` simply to access a property in a model class was pretty cumbersome. With the advent of lambda expression in Java 8, this is no longer the case, and using a lambda expression instead of the reflective `PropertyValueFactory` probably gives better performance, and, more importantly, provides compile-time checking.

First (and you should do this regardless), add property accessor methods to your `Credits` class. As your class currently stands, you create `StringProperty` instances, but there are no methods to access them (only methods to access their content). Consequently, your table won't dynamically update if you call, e.g. `setTitle()` on an already-displayed `Credits` instance. You just need to add

```
public class Credits {

    // all existing code...

    public StringProperty titleProperty() {
        return title ;
    }

    public StringProperty occupationProperty() {
        return occupation ;
    }

    public StringProperty personProperty() {
        return person ;
    }

}
```

Now you can just reference the properties directly in your `Credits` class:

```
title.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().titleProperty());
```

and similarly for the other columns. As well as the other benefits (primarily compile-time checking that the property actually exists), this also avoids the need to expose your `Credits` class reflectively to the `javafx.base` module.

Comment: And thanks a lot for the tip! Still new to programming with only half a year under my belt.